# Split scraped html string

Tags: python

I want to handle character strings up to 100K and write into a csv file into different columns. (basically trying to overcome excel cell limitation of 32K)

Below is sample code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
html = str(soup.select('div.DocumentText'))
if len(html) > 32000:
   #How to handle here and assign to different variable ex: html1, html2 is the question 
   x.writerow([html_1,......, html_5])
```

Example flow trying to achieve

- Scrape website
- If scraped data characters are greater than 32000 and less than 100K
- split the scraped into different variable
- write each variable into different columns of CSV file

Comment: do you mean that you want to split `c.case_html` into items of size 32k each?

Comment: You should post an example of a html input and the corresponding csv output you want to get.

Comment: Does the split need to occur on a word boundary?

Comment: yes on word boudary

Comment: I'd use stripped_strings method instead of str function if you're interested in words. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings

Comment: by the way if your question is answered it'll be great if you accept the most helpful answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps anyone... If there is a better way happy to hear.. Limitation is can handle only case_html(string) length upto 98K

```
def strhandler(case_html, length):
    string = case_html
    return (string[0+i:length+i] for i in range(0, len(string), length)) 

case_html = str(soup.find('div', class_='DocumentText').find_all(['p','center','small']))
char_count = len(c.case_html)
split_no = int(char_count/4)
print('Split this into no.of columns', split_no)
case_html_1, case_html_2, case_html_3, case_html_4, case_html_5 =  list(c.strhandler(case_html,split_no))
csv_writer.writerow([case_html_1, case_html_2, case_html_3, case_html_4, case_html_5,])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try this. It will split the string into sizes of 32000 (just change the size if you need to) and put them into a list.

```
if len(html) > 32000:
    #How to handle here and assign to different variable ex: html1, html2 is the question
    output = [html[0+i:32000+i] for i in range(0, len(html), 32000)]
    x.writerow(output)
```